# How to redirect from aspx page to html page in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developin web application in Angularjs. I have came across with different scenario. In my application i have payment gateway integration. I am redirecting customer to payment site. After payment gateway integration, gateway will send response using POST variable. So i have created file redirect.aspx.cs file and i am successfully getting reference number.

```
string payment_reference = Request.Form["payment_reference"];
```

Now after getting payment_reference i want to redirect to below state from my redirect.aspx.cs.

```
 $stateProvider
      .state('RedirectPage', {
          url: '/RedirectPage',
          templateUrl: 'App/LeaseRequest/PaymentRedirect.html',
          controller: 'PaymentRedirect',
          params: {
              payment_reference:null
          }
      });
```

May i know how can this can be done? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.